# How do these NM connectors work?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: nm connector]

What’s the purpose of the elongated plastic thing on the left side of the connector in this picture?

[image: second connector]

Similar question except this connector has the elongated plastic bit on the right. What is the purpose of the plastic bit with the ridges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both those pieces snap off and then are inserted after the cables are pushed through to secure the cables and prevent them from pulling out. The top one slides into the rectangular slot just above it in the picture. The lower one slides into the slot in the middle of the connector. They both lock in place after being pushed in against the cable so don't push them in before the cable is inserted.

Comment: Looks very much like a single-use cable clamp for a wire entrance into a metal box, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan   They are like cable ties.... you can get a real small slotted screwdriver in there and pry the locking clip back and release the cable and a pair of channellocks will release the connector from the box.

Comment: @FreeMan yes, those little tangs can be squeezed to get them to release.  Since their only purpose is saving time, and DIYers are not usually on the clock, I recommend sticking to traditional cable clamps, which can be used in more applications.